# Lock screen show all users instead of most recent user

Tags: macos, login, login-screen, touch-id

I'm using an M1 Macbook Air (2020) with Touch ID, running Mac OS Ventura 13.4.1

There are two user accounts set up on the laptop, each with Touch ID. When the laptop locks (automatically or when the lid is closed), upon re-opening it the mac shows the most recent user account. On this screen, Touch ID only works for the most recent user. In order to use Touch ID for a different user, you must click "Switch Users" to go back to the list of all users. Then, only on that screen, Touch ID works for any user and automatically detects and logs into the appropriate account based on which fingerprint is used.

Is it possible to automatically just show the list of all users every time the laptop wakes up? I know there is an option to "Automatically log in as" as well as an option for the login window to show either a "List of Users" or "Name and Password", but none of those solve the problem of having two people sharing a laptop, both with Touch ID.

It would be much more convenient if the laptop could always be ready to read any fingerprint at the login screen and automatically log onto the corresponding user account.

To explain what I mean, here's the current behavior:

1. Steve is logged in and closes the laptop.
2. Sally opens the laptop.
3. Laptop displays login screen for Steve
4. Sally must click "Switch User" to go back to the screen with all users
5. Sally scans her fingerprint, and it logs into "Sally" automatically

And here's the behavior I want to have:

1. Steve is logged in and closes the laptop.
2. Sally opens the laptop.
3. Laptop displays the user select screen (regardless of the most recent user)
4. Sally scans her fingerprint, and it logs into "Sally" automatically